# Export in react js based on a condition?

Tags: node.js, logging, reactjs

I have two loggers but i am facing a problem.
i want something similar to this. 
HOwever if i use only one logger without the if case then it works fine.

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'DEVELOPMENT')
{
    export default logger_dev;
}
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'PRODUCTION')
{
    export default logger_prod;
}
```

Comment: console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)

Comment: `export` cannot be dynamic like `require`. it is a *static* import.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
const logger = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'PRODUCTION' ? logger_prod : logger_dev;
export default logger;
```

Comment: Thanks ..should have thought a little more

Comment: Works also directly as `export default (myCondition) ? foo : bar;`

Answer (score 1):

You can only do one default. If you want to do multiple try below code

```
const g_twitter_handle = (l_twitter_handle != "") ? "https://www.twitter.com/"+l_twitter_handle : "";
export const twitter_handle = g_twitter_handle;

const g_facebook_handle = (l_facebook_handle != "") ? "https://www.facebook.com/"+l_facebook_handle : "";
export const facebook_handle = g_facebook_handle;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your logic is too complex to fit cleanly in a single ternary, you can abuse an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```js
export const logger = (() => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'PRODUCTION') {
        return logger_prod;
    } else {
        return logger_dev;
    }
})();
```

Overkill here but in my case I wanted to show or hide buttons to login in with various OAuth providers depending whether the deployment had the required environment variables set up and this worked nicely.